# Is there any way to not call the feeAndQuote API, instead calculate these things on chain and submit and order?

Tags: cow-protocol

When interacting with the protocol directly via the API, I wonder if its possible to avoid calling the feeAndQuote field but instead have my own system that calculates this based on onchain data and then allows me to submit the order to the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can create orders with 0 fee. The system will treat such orders as regular limit orders, re-calculate the appropriate fee for each auction and deduct it from the surplus.

You have to however ensure that your limit price has enough "room" for the fee. E.g. if you would like to swap 100 USDC for 100 USDT and expect a fee of 5$, your limit order needs to at least "sell 105 USDC for 100 USDT". This way, if 1USDC = 1USDT there will be 5USDC surplus, enough to cover the fee.

The smart contract can use PreSign or ERC1271 signatures to authorize this trade (by signing its order hash). Then, anyone can place the order parameters on behalf of the smart contract in the API.